# Read a file in Rust without moving BufReader

Tags: rust

I'm kinda new to rust so I have a problem with reading files right now. I am reading a file from path and I want to print its contents and as well use the same BufReader after printing. Here's a snippet of what I have

```
let file = File::open(path).map_err(|e| format!("failed to open file: {}", e))?;
          
let reader = BufReader::new(file);

println!("file name {}", path.display());
 
for line in reader.lines() {
    println!("{}", line.unwrap());
}
```

I tried to use `by_ref()` method, but the result is same.

```
let file = File::open(path).map_err(|e| format!("failed to open file: {}", e))?;
          
let reader = BufReader::new(file);

println!("file name {}", path.display());
 
for line in reader.lines().by_ref() {
    println!("{}", line.unwrap());
}
```

So the actual problem is that reader is being borrowed when calling `reader.lines()` or `reader.lines().by_ref()` and I can't use the same reader anymore. I want to use it in further code.

Comment: Please include in your question the actual problem you have, that is, what did you get that you did not expect, an error message, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`&mut impl BufRead` also implements `BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#impl-BufRead-for-%26mut+B) so you can just take a reference:

```rust
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
fn main() {
    let file: &[u8] = b"hello\nwolrd\n\n\n";

    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);

    for line in (&mut reader).lines() {
        println!("{}", line.unwrap());
    }
    let mut buf = String::new();
    dbg!(reader.read_line(&mut buf));
}
```

The key is taking the reference *before* calling `lines()` not afterwards.

But `lines` will read the underlying `Read` to it's end so there is probably nothing left to read after the for loop.

Comment: Or `reader.by_ref().lines()` from `Read`.

Comment: Reading helps, I got an compile error on `by_ref` but did not read to the point where it suggested importing `Read`

Comment: Well yeah, since it is from the `Read` trait you need to import it.

Comment: it seems that after the first read with `.lines()` I'm unable to do it once more and `.lines()` is not returning actual text

Comment: Yes that's what I mean by the last sentence. You probably want to collect the lines into a `Vec<String>` instead of what you stated in the question.